# How to move to the next / previous / right / left file tab on KDevelop with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: kdevelop, kdevelop4

Similar to Ctrl + Tab / Ctrl + Shift + Tab on Firefox.

Ctrl + Tab on KDevelop4 moves to the previously active tab much like Alt Tab changes applications on modern desktops.

But I just want to go left / right file tab as shown in the GUI above the editor.

KDevelop 4.7.3, Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, open `Settings -> Configure Shortcuts` menu and rebind `Ctrl+Tab` key to the `Next Window` action. This will give you classic `Ctrl+Tab` behavior.

Comment: Might be based on the `next document` string nowadays, since this is how to configure switching between tabs within Kile.